# How to convert PHP CSV output into excel with rich font styles and CSS in PHP

Tags: php

I tried to put font styles and color in EXCEL XLS sheet generation from CSV. Even i explored lots of libraries to get Excelsheet with enriched format and style.

Is there any libraries by which I can get formatted Excel XLS sheet from CSV output in PHP

Comment: Wait are you saying you want to output plain CSV, but with formatting like html or native Excel??? Cause you cant really do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It supports xlsx as well as just xls formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a flat web page with a table that has your font styles. Then download the table in excel using the code below.

```
header("Pragma: public"); 
$display="attachment";
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: $display; filename=$filename");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend good old http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/

```
require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';

$table = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$table->setTempDir($files_base.'/tmp');

$font= 'HelmetCondensed';

$f_std =& $table->addFormat();
$f_std->setFontFamily($font);

$f_b_c =& $table->addFormat();
$f_b_c->setFontFamily($font);
$f_b_c->setBold();
$f_b_c->setAlign('center');;

$table->write(0, 0, 'normal', $f_std);
$table->write(0, 1, 'bold+centered', $f_b_c);

// send HTTP headers
$table->send('NAME.xls');

// Let's send the file
$table->close();
```